# React-select clearable properties undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select package but when i click on clearable cross-icon it gives me error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

```
 <Select
                      className="form_control_country"
                      isClearable
                      onChange={onChangeStateHandler}
                      defaultValue={null}
                      disabled={navigationResponse != null ? true : false}
                      options={stateOptions}
                      placeholder={""}
                    ></Select>
```

this is onChange function

```
  const onChangeStateHandler = (e) => {
    setSelectedState(e.target.value);
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter of onChange callback is the new value (or values) of the select, not DOM event like standard select.

So you should be able to get the value directly:

```js
  const onChangeStateHandler = (newOption) => {
    // newOption can also be null 
    setSelectedState(newOption?.value);
  };
```

I'm assuming your options has a `value` property.

Looking at the [TypeScript types](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/Select.tsx#L219) it is clear

```js
  onChange: (
    newValue: OnChangeValue<Option, IsMulti>,
    actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>
  ) => void;
```